# Using the values of a var inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm working on a lms system and I'm having this problem

```
foreach($datas as $data){ ?>
   <div style="background-color: #3B4FDF; border-radius: 3%; width: 30%; height: 220px; margin-right: 5%; cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='classAdmin_list.php'">
     <p style="font-size: 1.5vw; color: white; position: relative; left: 7%; top: 0%;"> <?= $data['class_name'] ?> </p>
     <p style="font-size: 1vw; color: white; position: relative; left: 75%; top:  -25%;"> <?= $data['class_code'] ?> </p>
     <p style="font-size: 1vw; color: white; position: relative; left: 7%; top: 17%;"> <?= $data['school'] ?> </p>
<?php $_SESSION['className'] = $data['class_name']; ?>
     <img src="foto/balll.png" alt="ball" style="opacity: 0.5; width: 22%; height: 100px; position: relative; left: 75%; top: -30%;">
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is a code that creates a divs that look like this:
[image]

Those roman numbers are names. Im currently saving them inside a $_Session that is inside a foreach loop. And that is exactly the problem.

When i click the div it redirects me to a page that looks like this:
[image]

U see that (I-2).

I need that I-2 to be the class name (roman number) based on the div that it got clicked.

But that value is being saved on a $_Session, and that $_Session gets updated and overwrites previous values. so if i click on the 1 div (XII-3) it wont say : "Class XII-3" but "Class I-2".

Here is the code i use to make that "Class X"

```
<p>
      Class <span><?= $_SESSION['className'] ?></span>
</p>
```

I saw some questions but they were using for each loops so im asking because i cant find an answer

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: You should pass the class in a URL query parameter and not a session variable.

Comment: Why are you storing this in a session variable (that gets overwritten) to begin with? Use a URL parameter in your `onclick` and get that parameter in `classAdmin_list.php`

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this question tagged with MySQL or Javascript, but does not contain any such code? Where do you read the data from the session variable? Keep in mind that you can only store **a single** value in that variable, in each iteration of that loop you overwrite the former value

Comment: I think i got the answer, but the js and mysql tags are valid, the database is mysql and the i put the js cuz i thought the answer will contain js . And i didnt share all the code because: 1. there is alot and 2. privacy reasons . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good use case for sessions. Just pass the name in the URL as a query parameter:

```php
onclick="location.href='classAdmin_list.php?name=<?= urlencode($data['class_name']) ?>'">
```

(*Always use [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) when adding values the the URL to make sure they won't break the URL*)

and then use that on the `classAdmin_list.php`-page:

```php
Class <span><?= htmlentities($_GET['name']) ?></span>
```

(*Always use [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting data to protect against [XSS](https://blog.detectify.com/2019/03/15/what-are-the-different-types-of-xss/)*)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the `img` in some sort of anchor for example

```
<a href="/selected.php?className=<?=urlencode($data['class_name'])?>">
    <img src="foto/balll.png" alt="ball" style="opacity: 0.5; width: 22%; height: 100px; position: relative; left: 75%; top: -30%;">
</a>
```

Comment: _Typo:_ It's either `<?php echo` or `<?=`, not `<?php=`